# Expressions using matrix variables in SemidefiniteOptimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

The `SemidefiniteOptimization` function allows one to specify the region for the optimization variable, such as in

```
SemidefiniteOptimization[Tr[A], VectorGreaterEqual[{A, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}],  Element[A, Matrices[{2, 2}, Reals, Symmetric]]]
```

However, when using this notation, I cannot specify some types of constraints on `A`. If trying, for instance, to set `A[[1,1]] == 1` as a constraint, I get the errors

> Part::partd: Part specification A[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.

> SemidefiniteOptimization::ctuf: The function A[[1,1]] is neither convex or concave so the curvature of the constraint A[[1,1]]==1 cannot be determined.

Of course, one can make this work by explicitly stating `A` in terms of variables, e.g.,

```
A = {{a, b}, {b, d}};
SemidefiniteOptimization[Tr[A], {a == 1, VectorGreaterEqual[{A, 0}, "SemidefiniteCone", 2}]}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

but this becomes cumbersome for large problem instances.

Is there a way to make the first example work? Or is the second procedure really the standard way of doing this?

Comment: Try specifying the constraint as `Indexed[A, {1, 1}] == 1`